# How to separate a Column which contains NA´s by NA`s?

Tags: r, numbers, dataframe, na

This is first time I ask a question, so please be lenient :)

I think it's very simple. I have a data.frame which consists of one Column "Time". It looks like this:

```
-------------------------
> head(Times,10)
   Times
1     NA
2  0.448
3  0.130
4     NA
5     NA
6  0.462
7  0.427
8  0.946
9  0.227
10    NA
>
------------------------
```

The idea is, that a first NA signals the starting of a sequence, hence, following times should be from the same label. After reaching the next NA entry, the sequence is finished.

I wanted now to create a new data.frame, which takes numbers between NA`s into a columns and seperate the sequences by rows.

```
  Time1 Time2 Time3 Time4
1 0.448 0.130 0.123 
2 0.462 0.427 0.946 0.227
>
---------------------------------
```

Can you help?

Comment: Where did the `0.123` come from?

Comment: I am confused by your sample target df. The rows are sequences, but in your example input your first row should only have two columns. Is it correct that your new df[1,3] == ""?

Comment: Also, working with this, it strikes me that if you can you can reduce your management by removing the second `NA` between every run. If you have one `NA` its enough to signal the end of one sequence and the beginning of the next....

Comment: Sorry, the sample target df was made by my own, and therefore obviously wrong, the first row indeed shoud have just 2 columns...Thanks anyway for helping :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Times <- read.table(text = "Times
1     NA
2  0.448
3  0.130
4     NA
5     NA
6  0.462
7  0.427
8  0.946
9  0.227
10    NA", header = TRUE)

#identify values that belong together
Times$ind <- cumsum(is.na(Times$Times)) %/% 2 + 1

Times <- na.omit(Times) #remove NA values

#identify columns
Times$col <- unlist(tapply(Times$ind, factor(Times$ind), seq_along))

#reshape to wide format 
reshape(Times, timevar = "col", idvar = "ind", direction = "wide")
#  ind Times.1 Times.2 Times.3 Times.4
#2   1   0.448   0.130      NA      NA
#6   2   0.462   0.427   0.946   0.227
```

I've used base R for fun. If you need something more efficient, you should use package data.table.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Times %>% filter(!(is.na(Times) & is.na(lead(Times)))) %>%
          mutate(series = cumsum(is.na(Times)))  %>%
          filter(!is.na(Times)) %>%
          group_by(series) %>%
          mutate(count = paste0("Times.", row_number())) %>%
          spread(count, Times)

Source: local data frame [2 x 5]

  series Times.1 Times.2 Times.3 Times.4
   (int)   (dbl)   (dbl)   (dbl)   (dbl)
1      1   0.448   0.130      NA      NA
2      2   0.462   0.427   0.946   0.227
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table v1.9.6` (using data from @Roland's answer):

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6+
setDT(Times)[, `:=`(grp = seq_len(.N), rle = rle), by = .(rle = rleid(is.na(Times)))]
dcast(na.omit(Times, by="Times"), rle ~ grp, value.var="Times")
#    rle     1     2     3     4
# 1:   2 0.448 0.130    NA    NA
# 2:   4 0.462 0.427 0.946 0.227
```

You can use `paste0("Times", rle)` to get the column names as shown in your Q.

Comment: Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘data.table v1.9.6’ is not available (for R version 3.0.0)....d´oh